# Identify those characters which differs

Tags: c#

I'm supposed to write a program which identifies the differences between pairs of strings to make it easier for humans to see the differences.

The program should identify those characters which differ between the two given strings in a visually striking way.

Output the two input strings on two lines, and then identify the differences on the line below using periods (for identical characters) and asterisks (for differing characters).

For example:

```
ATCCGCTTAGAGGGATT
GTCCGTTTAGAAGGTTT
*....*.....*..*..
```

The first line of input contains an integer 
1≤n≤500, indicating the number of test cases that follow. Each test case is a pair of lines of the same length, 1 to 50 characters. Each string contains only letters (a-z, A-Z) or digits (0-9).

But I cant change the matching characters to pointers? can I get some help? 
And I don't really understand how to indicate the number of test cases?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s1 = "abcdefg";
            string s2 = "acceeff";

        string s3 = "hbcdfgi";
        string s4 = "hbadehi";

            char[] c1 = s1.ToCharArray();
            char[] c2 = s2.ToCharArray();
            char[] c3 = s3.ToCharArray();
            char[] c4 = s4.ToCharArray();

            var diff = s1.Except(s2);
            string newS1 = s1;
            foreach(var value in diff)
            {
                newS1 = newS1.Replace(value, '*');

            }
        var diff2 = s3.Except(s4);
            string newS2 = s3;
         foreach(var value in diff2)
            {

        newS2 = newS2.Replace(value, '*'); 

            }
        string nr1 = s1 + "\n" + s2;
        string nr2 = s3 + "\n" + s4;

        Console.WriteLine(nr1);
        Console.WriteLine(newS1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(nr2);
        Console.WriteLine(newS2);
        Console.WriteLine();
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are storing your test cases to be able to comment on that, but basically foreach test case you just need to output the 2 values, and then loop one of them to check for matches and output the correct char based on the match.

So for each test case (pair of strings) you just want to do something like this:

```
string s1 = "abcdefg";
string s2 = "acceeff";

// Write each input string to console.
Console.WriteLine(s1);
Console.WriteLine(s2);

// Loop each character and check for match.
for(int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
{
    if(s1[i] == s2[i]) // If match output "."
        Console.Write(".");
    else // otherwise, output "*"
        Console.Write("*");
}

// Write a new line ready for the next test case.
Console.WriteLine();
```

---

With regards to looping test cases, you basically want a `List` of a customer class that holds the strings. For example:

```
class TestCase
{
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public string S2 { get; set; }
}
```

You would then need to create a list somehow (maybe read from a file or hard code):

```
List<TestCase> testCases = new List<TestCase>
{
    new TestCase { S1 = "abcdef", S2 = "abcxyz" },
    new TestCase { S1 = "abc", S2 = "def" }
};
```

Which you then loop like so:

```
foreach(var testCase in testCases)
{
    string s1 = testCase.S1;
    string s2 = testCase.S2;

    // Rest of code from above.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it! It was a lot simpler than I thought :)